# How do i fix and open mouth

Tags: mesh

I downloaded this model but some vertex in the mouth are joined and cant even open the mouth with proportional editing https://www.deviantart.com/o0demonboy0o/art/Sly-Cooper-411593500 can someone help me to fix it is there a way?

Comment: ripping models (or downloading them) is not cool, some day you will maybe make models like this yourself or you will own a game studio, then you will understand better. If you made it yourself, people would be much more willing to help instead of helping a thief.

Comment: In Edit mode select the Edge and select Mesh/Edges/Edge Split

Comment: Thanks! and dont worry jaro is just for a nude edit